# Hide a certain element in XML preview but show it on device?

Tags: android, eclipse

This is not a directly programming related question but I don't know where else to ask and I am running out of ideas where to look.

Is there a way to hide a certain element from XML preview but still show it when the app is compiled? I don't mean the "visibility" attribute. If you set visibility to gone, the device also won't show that view. What I want is to simply hide a certain element from xml preview.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can hide it using the visibility attribute on your xml layout file, and show it programmatically at runtime.

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

**EDIT**

Apparently there's a better way of doing this, in case you're using Android Studio, as of v0.2.11 you can take advantage of designtime layout attributes, for example:

1. Include this in your layout:

   ```
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   ```
2. Change visibility attribute:

   ```
   tools:visibility="invisible"
   ```

Full example and documentation [available here](http://tools.android.com/tips/layout-designtime-attributes).